# file_get_contents returns empty string in shared host

Tags: php, json, web-services, file-get-contents, datasnap

I'm trying get url contents with file_get_contents(), its works in my localhost server, but in shared host server, the function returns a empty string, **without errors**. My code follows:

```
$uri = 'http://my_url.com:81/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods/getLoginCliente/galf/123/';
$result = file_get_contents($uri);
var_dump($result);
```

and the result is:

```
string(0) ""
```

instead of:

```
{result: [4532,1]}
```

**I'm test change the url for google.com, and works perfectly.**

Anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Does opening that url in your browser work as expected?

Comment: in browser and in localhost server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the firewall host. The firewall is block the port 81.

Answer (score 1):

Check if fopen url wrappers are enabled :

```
var_export(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
```

I suppose it is just disabled as potentially insecure operation.

Comment: **I'm test change the url for google.com, and works perfectly.**

Comment: sorry, then I'm not sure what can cause that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your php file

```
// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And then look for any errors that it gives you. the shared host might have disabled that particular function and in order to have it work you'll have to ask them to enable it.

Comment: no errors. I'm test change the url for google.com, and works perfectly, therefore the function is active.